# Image is not displaying over header using z-index?

Tags: css

Okay so i have this website: lendenapp.com, and the theme is using triangle images to give a slant to each section, if you take a look you will understand.

The Issue is that the Top 2 Triangle images are not displaying over the section, the others lower though are.

I am not sure what i am missing, perhaps its a very simple css issue?

Here is the code:

```css
.triangleTop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 99;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<img class="triangleTop" src="http://lendenapp.com/wp-content/themes/delicious/img/tri-white-top.png" alt="">
```

If you seen more code you can please ask and i can provide it.
Thanks
Alex

Comment: Your code example doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry about the short of the code but I wasn't exactly sure what I should enter that's why I left it for request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `overflow-x: hidden;` on the `#contentWrapper` that causes the problem. If you remove it it works as intended, and it doesn't seem to be needed anyway?

Comment: Okay thanks I'll give that a try about 1 hour and will update the result.

Comment: @Savenz Savisaar Kulbach, glad it worked!